# in java,how to access same JNI method from diffrent jvm

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have two separate Java applications which are deployed in JBoss. I also have JNI method(for example "test"). Now I want to access this method from the both applications. How to achieve this.

Comment: load the dll and make a call to the method?

Answer (score 1):

you just load the shared library in both the java applications.it works in a similar manner like it did for single application